# cocoa downloading file callbacks not called when downloaded from background thread, works on main thread

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am new to cocoa programming , I am trying to download binary file from a url to disk. Unfortunately the methods are not calledback for some reason. The call to downloadFile is made from a background thread started via [self performSelectorOnBackground] etc. Any ideas what am I doing wrong ?

**NOTE
When I make call to downloadFile from main UI thread, it seems to work, what's up with background thread ?**

```
-(BOOL) downloadFile
{
        BOOL downloadStarted = NO;
        // Create the request.
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:versionLocation]
                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                timeoutInterval:60.0];

    // Create the connection with the request and start loading the data.
        NSURLDownload  *theDownload = [[NSURLDownload alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest
                                                                                                                                delegate:self];
    if (theDownload) {
        // Set the destination file.
        [theDownload setDestination:@"/tmp" allowOverwrite:YES];
                downloadStarted = YES;
    } else {
        // inform the user that the download failed.
                downloadStarted = NO;
    }

        return downloadStarted;

}


- (void)download:(NSURLDownload *)download didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Release the connection.
    [download release];

    // Inform the user.
    NSLog(@"Download failed! Error - %@ %@",
          [error localizedDescription],
          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
}

- (void)downloadDidFinish:(NSURLDownload *)download
{
    // Release the connection.
    [download release];

    // Do something with the data.
    NSLog(@"%@",@"downloadDidFinish");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start the run loop to which your NSURLDownload object is attached. By default it will use the current thread's run loop, so you probably should do something like this after initialization of NSURLDownload object:

```
NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
while (!self.downloaded && !self.error && [runLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]])
        ;
```

Properties self.downloaded and self.error should be set in your callbacks.
 
In main thread run loop probably started by the NSApplication object.